# What is the "t" permission on HDFS directories?

Tags: hadoop, posix, hdfs

A HDFS directory, when seen in Cloudera Hue, appears to have the following permission flags:

```
drwxrwxrwxt
```

I understand that it is a directory (*d*), that can be used in read/write mode (*rw*) by all users and that all users can access the children (*x*).

What does the last flag *t* mean ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `t` flag is called a sticky bit. A sticky bit is a permission bit that is set on a directory that allows only the owner of the file within that directory or the root user to delete or rename the file. No other user has the needed privileges to delete the file created by some other user.

This is a security measure to avoid deletion of critical folders and their content (sub-directories and files), though other users have full permissions.